# Does Angular2 offer namespacing of items registered with the injector?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

In Angular 1 you had "modules" that offered little more than a grouping of items to be registered with the injector.

Does Angular 2 offer anything further when it comes to the namespacing of services etc registered with the injector?

Comment: you can be more explicit, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular [`NgModule`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule) modules [were introduced in Angular 2.0.0 RC5](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc5-2016-08-09) exactly for this reason, to provide injectables with structure and hierarchy.

Angular team tried to rely solely on ES6 modules before that (sets of providers were just grouped in arrays and exported), but this design had too many flaws.

Angular 2+ modules share same idea with AngularJS modules and offer same functionality and some more, such as [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#lazy-loading-modules-with-the-router).